# Javascript send data to function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to make Generator class as a parent, and a number of child. So i define default constructor and parent function like this:

```
  function Generator (){
   this._startIndex=0;
    this._endIndex=61;
    alert("Generator Ready " + this._startIndex + " " + this._endIndex);
}

Generator.prototype.make=function() {
    alert (this._startIndex);

} 
var worker= new Generator();

document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", worker.make);
```

but in this case "this" is a Button, and this._startIndex is undefined.

In case, i call function like:

```
document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", worker.make(warker._startIndex));
```

The function called not on click, but onload.
I shure, this is simple question, but more than hour i cant find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword has different meanings depending on the scope and who's calling a function.

To *force* `this` to hold what you want, you'll need to use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", worker.make.bind(worker));
```

Or you can also use a *closure*...

```
document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", function() {
    worker.make();
});
```

Comment: @tri___ton No problem. Welcome to the magical world of `this` on JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 0):

In line 
`document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", worker.make);` when `worker.make` get's called it is not bound with worker object,you can achieve this by

`document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click", worker.make.bind(worker));`

or

```
document.getElementById("but0").addEventListener("click",function(){
worker.make();
})
```

Comment: Thank you. But Matiaz was faster. 
And answer is identical.
I think you both have default constructor for stupid newbie question. ))))

Comment: Ahhh mised by lots seconds...:D